# Why does this df give me NA's in the graph when there are not any Na's in the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my head(df):

```
head(dfneg)
   Journey.Area Experience.Framework Positive.or.Negative
1 Using Product            Execution                   -1
2      Delivery            Execution                   -1
3    Installing     People/Associate                   -1
4    Installing            Execution                   -1
5 Using Product            Execution                   -1
6      Browsing     People/Associate                   -1
```

Here is put(head(df)):

```
> dput(head(dfneg))
structure(list(Journey.Area = c("Using Product", "Delivery", 
"Installing", "Installing", "Using Product", "Browsing"), Experience.Framework = c("Execution", 
"Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", "Execution", "People/Associate"
), Positive.or.Negative = c(-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is summary of df:

```
> summary((dfneg))
 Journey.Area       Experience.Framework Positive.or.Negative
 Length:67          Length:67            Min.   :-1          
 Class :character   Class :character     1st Qu.:-1          
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character     Median :-1          
                                         Mean   :-1          
                                         3rd Qu.:-1          
                                         Max.   :-1
```

Here is my code for the graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
    dfneg %>% 
      mutate(Journey.Area = factor(Journey.Area, 
  levels = c("Getting Assistance", "Returning", "Using Product", "Installing", 
             "Delivery", "Pickup", "Anticipating", "Buying", 
             "Deciding How to Buy", "Browsing"))) %>%
  count(Journey.Area,Experience.Framework) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Journey.Area,n,fill=Experience.Framework)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(fill="", x="Customer Journey Area", y="User Experience Framework") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + ggtitle("Customer Sentiment Matrix") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Everything line in my df is attributed to one of the Customer Journey Areas and there are no NAs. Why ggplot doing this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Hard to tell without the full data but I would double-check your mutate line when generating the graph. A typo in the levels of the factor function could lead to NAs

Comment: Most likely reason is that you introduce `NA`s when converting your `Journey.Area` column to a factor. If your `Journey.Area` contains categories not present in the `levels` argument these will be converted to NAs, e.g. `factor(c("A", "B"), levels = c("A", "C"))` will return `c("A", NA)`.